# Alguien podria solucionar este error en java, "el error dice que in cannot be dereferenced" no se como se podria solucionar ese error

Tags: java

```java
private void btnBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String dni = txtDNI.getText();
        
        IControllerBase<Cliente> objCliCont = new ClienteController();
        
        List<Cliente> listaClientes = objCliCont.consultarTodos();
        
        List<Cliente> listaOrdenada = listaClientes.stream().filter(
                                        **c -> c.getDni().startsWith(dni))**                                        
                                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Cliente::getDni).reversed())
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: Hola Nilson, primero tienes que sacar los asteríscos, sin ver tu código, adivino que **getDni()** devuelve un entero, y lo que espera la función, es una cadena, de ahi el error, o bien cambias entero por cadena, o reescribes la función... eso si no me equivoco.